# Connectwise REST API Implementation using python

Tags: python-2.7

In my application , I am going to use connectwise API , but I can't figure out how to call their API, like

```
How to connect
How to pass header (json data)
How to authentication (I have company id , public and private key)
How to make call and take response
```

I am Python guy
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

This question is quite broad, and you'll need to get familiar with something such as the [Requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/) if you aren't already.

Also, ConnectWise has a lot of documents at [their developer site](http://developer.connectwise.com/Manage/REST) and registration is free and easy.

However I went through this journey myself over the last few weeks and learnt a lot so I'll share it with you.

## Authentication

Authentication is done by creating an API user. In CW Manage you can create a member user with the API license class.

In ConnectWise Manage:

1. Go to System => Members
2. Go to the API Members tab.
3. Create a new API member that gives the API access to the areas that you need it, such as corporate/territorial levels. Note the username, amd that you cannot specify a password. Complete all the mandatory fields (owner ID, system default, group, approvers, etc).
4. When you have made this user go to the API keys tab. Enter a description for your new set of keys, and save it. When you do this you'll see the public and private keys once (and once only). Note them down.

## Authorisation Header

In Python:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode("a+b:c")
```

...where a is your ConnectWise company name (what you type in in the login box), b is your public key, and c is your private key. This will return something which will be what you use to access the system. Copy it.

## Making your first request

Now in Python make a new file and put this in it (this is quick and dirty but it should get you started):

```
import requests

cwToken = ""
# This is the ConnectWise access code generated earlier

cwUrl = "https://api-eu.myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/" 
# check the URL matches your region, look at your CW Manage login box if not

cwHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + cwToken,
             "clientID":"<insertyoursecretClientIDhere>",
             "Content-Type":"application/json"}
# this is your authorisation payload

try:
    r = requests.get(cwUrl + "company/companies?pageSize=1000&conditions=type/id==1", headers=cwHeaders)
    # request has been made
    r.raise_for_status()
except:
    print(r.text)
    raise

companies = r.json()
```

The companies object now contains a list of your first 1,000 clients (type is ID 1 -- client). I've included an example of the conditions string because it took me a while to work out what it is and how to use it. But just take it off if you don't want the server to do your filtering for you.

You'll then be able to modify the above, or turn it into a module (which is what I did) to then make quick and portable calls, something like

```
cw.getCompanies()
```

which would simply return you a JSON object with all your companies in.

## Going further

Study the documentation!! It is comprehensive enough to get you started. And the forums are actively monitored by staff (although they help mostly with C# queries and not scripting).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer .

Answer (score 3):

Just an update for 2020 since Daniel's response was incredibly helpful, but is missing a change Connectwise made in 2019 that now requires ClientIDs in order to auth.

Make a client ID here (scroll to bottom, although it's quick and useful to read all of it):
https://developer.connectwise.com/ClientID#What_is_a_clientId.3F

Daniel's code should then look like:

```
cwHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + cwToken,
             "clientID":"<insertyoursecretClientIDhere>",
             "Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

Comment: Thank you - added the changes to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this thread incase others find this helpful - I've developed a library to make working with the ConnectWise API in Python significantly easier called pyConnectWise. It's been developed with the intention of it being easy to pick up for non-coders, but still allowing experienced coders to utilize the full features of the API without the annoying boilerplate.

You can find it with source and instructions at https://github.com/HealthITAU/pyconnectwise

Hope this helps anyone that comes across here!